# Execute actionListener before ajax?

Tags: java, ajax, jsf

How can I execute an actionListener before a ajax request?

```
<h:commandButton actionListener=.. action=..>
<f:ajax render="test">
</h:commandButton>
```

order of execution is:

```
test
actionListener
action
```

What can I change so that actionListener method is executed before f:ajax?

---

Full example:

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandButton value="test" actionListener="#{bean.toggleProgress}" action="#{bean.do()}" > 
        <f:ajax execute="@form" render="progress" />
    </h:commandButton>

    <h:panelGroup id="progress" >
        <h:outputText rendered="#{bean.progress}" />
    </h:panelGroup> 
</h:form>

class Bean {

    private progress = false;

    public boolean isProgress() {
        System.out.println("in: ajax")
        return progress;
    }

    public toggleProgress(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("in: actionListener")
        progress = true;
    }

    public void do() {
        System.out.println("in: action")
    }
}
```

systout is:

```
in: ajax
in: actionListener
in: action
```

Comment: What you're describing is not true. It must be a misinterpretation. I think the latter as you don't have anywhere a `<f:ajax listener>`. Perhaps you're confusing JavaScript `onclick` or so with Java?

Comment: Indeed it is! edited above with full example.

Comment: Is the sysout from during a form submit? Are you sure that the 1st line isn't from the initial GET request?

Comment: yes the initial GET request produces a "in: ajax" additionally. But the sysout above is just from the submit!

Comment: Well, I've never seen that. What JSF impl/version are you using? Your full example by the way doesn't compile, but that'll be the carelessness :/

Comment: apache-tomee-plus-1.1.0-SNAPSHOT with myfaces-impl-2.1.8.jar, openwebbeans-jsf-1.1.5.jar